# can i combine path.lineTo() and path.addCircle() in android?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to draw circles on where I touch and along with my movement on the screen. if i travel really fast, the screen would have spotty circles. Is it possible that I can combine `addCircle()` and `lineTo()`? so for example if I first touched (100, 100), then quickly move my finger to (100, 150). I would get a result of two circles on the screen, but instead, I want to draw circles from (100, 100) all the way to (100, 150), just like what `lineTo()` would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that's possible. The only way I could imagine it working as you describe is if [`lineTo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#lineTo(float,%20float)) allowed you to provide a `Paint` object with some sort of tiling behavior, but that's not the case.

To achieve the same effect, you could manually calculate sets of coordinates that lie between `(100, 100)` and `(100, 150)` using e.g. [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation#Linear_interpolation) and then draw circles at those coordinates in addition to the existing circles. For example, if you wanted the maximum circle separation to be `5px`, you would draw additional circles at the following locations:

```
(100, 105)
(100, 110)
...
(100, 145)
```

Comment: thats what I thought too. why is there a `circleTo` method. thanks for the suggestion tho!